# VB.NET and RESTful service

Tags: javascript, .net, vb.net, tcp, visual-studio-express

I'm trying to build a simple VB.NET/Express 2012 windows application that will be able to receive a POST or JSON object with two parameters:

1. an XML document
2. an array or object of parameters

It will get its data from a front-end through JavaScript. That on itself makes a query to the back-end getting the needed info and will then trigger a print task on the local machine where this software is running using a local port to 'talk' to the local application.

I'm just looking for the components to use or some simple examples. Preferably I'd like to run a background TCP listening service that works on it's own (possibly a threaded task inside the application) and fires an event when needed.

Please, remember that it has to be made on the **Express** version of Visual Studio. I do not have all the extended possibilities the regular Studio has.

All the help is appreciated.

BTW, I've found [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766653/tcp-server-in-vb-net) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608062/vb-net-service-programming-and-using-tcp-sockets), but they don't seem to going in the direction I'm wanting to go, as in that they run a continuous loop that seems to disable any and all other input or interaction unless you quit (kill) the application.

[edit]
I'm **not** creating a web application/server - I'm using a PHP solution for that. It's supposed to be a sort-of printserver.
[/edit]

Comment: Have you looked at MVC? You should be able to include it in your project from NuGet.

Comment: @AdamZuckerman And how does MVC help me in this case (although MVC isn't bad by itself)? I just need a listener service that will be triggered by a client request... :)

Comment: MVC will let you build RESTful web services (web api) easily. That will give you the option to use either XML or JSON.